# Jenkins Build step ‘Execute Windows batch command’ marked build as failure’

Tags: jenkins, build

I want to run some commands in Build => Windows batch command but I don't really know what the problem was ?

`C:\Users\LZNOVO\Downloads\nuget.exe  restore “C:\Users\LZNOVO\Downloads\NetCoreMicroservicesSample-master\NetCoreMicroservicesSample-master\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.sln” -ConfigFile C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer.2838104e5c7a43518abce52cca05b8f8\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\nuget.config`

And here's what I got

````
.
.
.
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 852d5f90b1dc6faeabed0825e8645f2421bfd915 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Set up CI with Azure Pipelines"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 852d5f90b1dc6faeabed0825e8645f2421bfd915 # timeout=10
[net] $ cmd /c call /tmp/jenkins748041003533296782.bat
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/home/fatine/.jenkins/workspace/net"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:254)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:223)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:997)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:509)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:144)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:92)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:814)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:522)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1896)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE ```
````

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run a windows command (`cmd` and `.bat`) on a linux machine ( this `"/"`, not `"\"`): `cmd /c call /tmp/jenkins748041003533296782.bat` and so `cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/home/fatine/.jenkins/workspace/net"): error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: In fact, I just use Ubuntu terminal on windows machine

Comment: This is a Jenkins issue and/or a Windows issue; you might want to add the appropriate windows and/or WSL tags.